# Reverse a Javascript Build

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a javascript build file, that is unminified; it contains prototype class definitions. Is there any tool i can use to break the build file into separate files, assuming one file per prototype/class definition?

This build file looks like the following, with many objects defined in the following way, all concatenated into the single file.  I would like to break this file apart.  I don't have access to the original source code, I was basically just given a dump in the form of this build file but its unmanageable in this form as its 10k+ lines of code.

```
MyClass = function(){
}
MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
}
```

Comment: In the the time you spend look for/building a tool, you could split that file by hand and have a cup of tea. 10K lines isn't a lot if all you're doing is separating constructors into different files.

Comment: Yes, however, I may also need to figure out all the interdependencies, and either convert to node modules, or use require.js or something similar.  Are there ide's that have refactoring tools for class extraction, similar to Java in Eclipse?

Comment: Grep for constructor definitions and split by those line numbers

Comment: Well, as long as you include the files in the order that you separate them you shouldn't get interdependency errors. But you'll have to manually refactor into commonJS/requireJS because I can't think of a tool to do that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the suggested (in comments) do it manually manner, but if you insist to automate it some way, you can always use javaScript for the job.

One way would be to look up for constructors throw a regex like `([^\.=\s]+[^=]*=[\s]*function[\s]*[(]+[^)]*[)][\s]*[{]*)` and extract all 'class'.prototype.'something' from the file, parse the entire file then write each group in separate files after doing any kind of ordering you would prefer.

Another manner would be to use a javaScript parser and group relevant function definitions throw token examination (this one is overkill, but might be interesting for learning purposes).